# How to generate a listing of branches with Intel Pin tool?

Tags: linux, cpu-architecture, instructions, intel-pin

I am relatively new to using the Intel Pin tool for code instrumentation and I am attempting to study Branch Prediction. Specifically, I would like to generate a listing of all the branches, their branch targets, and whether they are taken/not taken. I know there are pintools in the SimpleExamples for generating memory address traces such as the "pinatrace.cpp" tool, but I don't see any that suit my needs for listing branches.

Is there an existing pintool somewhere in the examples that I can use, or will I need to write a new pintool?

I am using pin-2.14 on a Linux computer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure that there is a example pintool that does this, but this can be done relatively simply.

If I understand you correctly, you want 3 things:

1. Address of all conditional branches
2. Targets
3. Taken/Not taken decision

1/2. This can be accomplished by using instruction level instrumentation. Use the `INS_AddInstrumentFunction(Instruction, 0)` in order to allow the function `Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v)` to be called every time a new instruction is about to be executed. Then within that `Instruction()` function, you can use `if(INS_IsBranch(ins) && INS_HasFallThrough(ins))` expression to determine if the current instruction is a conditional branch. If it is, store its address `INS_Address(ins)` along with it's target `INS_DirectBranchOrCallTargetAddress(ins)`. Perhaps you can print its disassembly for debugging purposes `INS_Disassemble(ins)`.

3.In order to print out the decision, you have to insert an analysis routine before every conditional branch. Using the Instruction function above, within the `if(INS_IsBranch(ins) && INS_HasFallThrough(ins))`, use this API call:

`INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)<YOUR FUNCTION NAME>, IARG_INST_PTR, IARG_BRANCH_TAKEN, IARG_END)`

Using this, you can create an analysis routine that will run every time a conditional branch is dynamically executed. From there using the IARG_BRANCH_TAKEN argument, you can do a simple check to determine if the branch was taken or not. Store the decision in a map or something like a map so that later you can print it out. WARNING: Don't print anything out in an analysis routine (it's never a good idea to print out a dynamic trace of instructions). Also note that a conditional branch may run more than once with different taken/not taken decision so you may have to keep track of more than one decision.

Hope this helps.

CHEERS,

Danny

Comment: Thanks @dannykim. I ended up modifying the `ToolUnitTests/branch_target_addr.cpp` Pin tool to suit my needs, but the end result looked very similar to the method you described.